# Get current category and place it in shortcode

Tags: shortcode, categories

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[x_recent_posts type="post" count="2" offset="" category="Lisbon" orientation="vertical" no_sticky="true" no_image="false" fade="false"]');
            ?>
```

This is the shortcode, and I need to get category name and place it in shortcode. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Erm, the code you added _completely_ changes the question - in the future please be more clear from the start.

Comment: I know, and I am really sorry. I have posted this on mobile, and pasted the code, but afrer reading your question I have realsied that code isn't showing. When I edited my question code was there, and I needed to add it as code in text editor. I apologize!

Comment: So when you say "get category name", you mean the name of the current category archive? (if it is one)

Comment: Exactly. Theme has that shortcode and I need to place category name in it. It would be great if I can get some variable that will get category name and I can place it shortcode so when user goes to category it shows posts from that category with that shortcode. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can get the category name with `get_queried_object()->name`:

```
if ( is_category() ) {
    echo do_shortcode( '[x_recent_posts type="post" count="2" offset="" category="' . get_queried_object()->name . '" orientation="vertical" no_sticky="true" no_image="false" fade="false"]' );
}
```